# WSO2APIM: programmatically add Identity provider

Tags: ansible, wso2-api-manager, wso2

Is it possible to add Identity providers to WSO2 APIM (2.6.0) programmatically? With Ansible or APIs or other ways?
One solution that I can see is to add record directly to database by Ansible. But is there any other easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IdentityProviderMgtService` Admin Service (`https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityProviderMgtService?wsdl`) to add IdPs. Refer this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+the+Identity+Provider+API#UsingtheIdentityProviderAPI-addIdp).